# Generating PDF from XML using XSL:FO. Transforming the hyperlink content from XML to PDF

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

How to transform the below XML that contains the hyperlink tag to PDF using XSL:FO

```
    <paragraphs>
     <paragraph>ahsbdgdgdg<a href="https://aaaa.com/xsd &did=jsjsj">Test</a>
     </paragraph>
    </paragraphs>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fo:basic-link` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_basic-link) and put the URI in `external-destination` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#external-destination):

```
<fo:basic-link
  external-destination="url(https://aaaa.com/xsd%20&amp;did=jsjsj)">test</fo:basic-link>
```

The URI has to be well-formed XML, so the `&` in your example has to be `&amp;` in your XML.

Whether or not you need to escape the space as `%20` possibly depends on which formatter you are using.  If you were using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0, you would have built-in functions available to you for escaping the URI.

The XSL 1.1 Recommendation says that you need `url(` and `)` before and after the URI, but probably most formatters will let you omit that.

Comment: Thank-you, Tony. Could you please let me know, how to write the XSLT to transform the above XML to PDF using XSL:FO basic link that you have mentioned.

Comment: That's a bit too much for a comment.  There's multiple resources available for how to use XSLT, including "How to Develop Stylesheets for XML to XSL-FO Transformation" at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/xml-to-xsl-fo-stylesheets/