# Create Clickable External Link in XSL for PDF Creation

Tags: xml, hyperlink, xsl-fo

I'm trying to create a clickable hyperlink in my xsl code.  This xsl receives xml input and creates a pdf bill for customers.  I'm trying to make the hyperlink work, but I can't find any solution online.

I've searched the internet and can't find any solution that works. I've tried using an anchor tag around my url as well as fo:basic-link.

```
<xsl:if test="@donation = '0.00' and @outputpastduemsg != 'true'">
              <fo:block  padding-top=".15in" color="black" font-size="9pt">Please visit 

<fo:basic-link external-destination="https://blahblahblah.org/donations">

to discover ways that you can help those in critical financial need.
              </fo:block>
</xsl:if>
```

I'd expect to see the created pdf with a hyperlink, but when I try to view the pdf in the application it gives me a pop up window with the following

"Not Found

The requested URL /pm/once-off/Statement-for-67002_1562332338838.pdf was not found on this server."

Answer (score 2):

Your sample XML is not well-formed since the `fo:basic-link` does not have an end-tag.

Similarly to [Generating PDF from XML using XSL:FO. Transforming the hyperlink content from XML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711204/generating-pdf-from-xml-using-xslfo-transforming-the-hyperlink-content-from-xm/52715559#52715559), put the URI in `external-destination` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#external-destination):

```
<fo:basic-link
  external-destination="url(https://blahblahblah.org/donations)">blahblahblah.org</fo:basic-link>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been trying to get this to work for two days.